# operator overloading in templated class with multiple types

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a templated vector class that can be based on any arithmetic type and do math with them. So a Vec3<T> + Vec3<U> should be permitted. Here is my declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class Vec3 {
private:
    T _x, _y, _z;
public:
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Type must be arithmetic");
    Vec3(T x, T y, T z);
    ~Vec3() = default;
    
    template <typename U, typename V>
    friend Vec3<T> operator+(Vec3<U> lhs, const Vec3<V>& rhs);    
};
```

I wrote two definitions for this function (same hpp file but further down), one if all input types are the same the output type should be the same. But if one of them is different the output depends: int+double-> double, double+int -> double, long+int -> long, ... you get the idea.

```
template <typename T>
Vec3<T> operator+(Vec3<T> lhs, const Vec3<T>& rhs) {
    return Vec3<T>(T x, T y, T z);
}

template <>
Vec3<double> operator+(Vec3<int> lhs, const Vec3<double>& rhs) {
    return Vec3<double>(double x, double y, double z);
}

template <>
Vec3<double> operator+(Vec3<double> lhs, const Vec3<int>& rhs) {
    return Vec3<double>(double x, double y, double z);
}
...
```

I thought I would overload the operator+ for every combination of permissible types. However I'm getting an error:

```
error: template-id 'operator+><' for 'Color3<double> operator+(Color3<int>, const Color3<double>&)' does not match any template declaration
```

What's the proper way to go about setting up any number of possible combinations of types? Thanks.

Comment: Remove `template <>`.  Those functions are not specializations of any template function. That will bring you to your next error.  `Vec3<double>` is a **type**, so `return Vec3<double>;` does not make sense.

Comment: Please note that you need to pass `lhs` by reference.

Comment: After your edit, `return Vec3<double>();` will not compile either.  Look at that type's only constructor.

Comment: @DrewDormann Sorry about that, when simplifying I removed too much - the return statement should just show what type I want to return. I added () to correct.

Comment: @DrewDormann when removing <> i get a new error that just says "/filepath/file.hpp: line X: first defined here" - X is the line of the first Vec3<double>

Comment: *"int+double-> double, double+int -> double, long+int -> long, ... you get the idea."* -- I think I get it, but let me check. You are saying that if someone adds a `Vec3<X>` and a `Vec3<Y>` the result should be a vector of the result of adding an `X` and a `Y`, a.k.a. a `Vec3<decltype(X{}+Y{})>`?

Comment: @JaMiT yes, exactly!

Comment: `return Vec3<double>(double x, double y, double z);` -- this is invalid C++. This is like writing `return int;` in a non-template function. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: With the many edits happening to the code shown here, please remember to check that the code you are showing produces the error you are showing.

Comment: `return Vec3<T>(T x, T y, T z);` ... no, that's not going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any two `Vec3` based entities to be able to use `operator+` you can add a `friend` that deduces the proper return type: `Vec3<decltype(U{} + V{})>`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vec3 {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Type must be arithmetic");

    Vec3(T x, T y, T z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {}
    ~Vec3() = default;

    // matches any two Vec3<>s
    template <class U, class V>
    friend Vec3<decltype(U{} + V{})> operator+(const Vec3<U>& lhs,
                                               const Vec3<V>& rhs);

private:
    T _x, _y, _z;
};

template <class U, class V>
Vec3<decltype(U{} + V{})> operator+(const Vec3<U>& lhs, const Vec3<V>& rhs) {
    return {lhs._x + rhs._x, lhs._y + rhs._y, lhs._z + rhs._z};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to the question as posed, but a demo of how easy this is to write if you organize your data into something compatible with ranges:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename... R>
auto vsum(F&& f, R&& ...ranges)
{
    return std::views::zip_transform(
        std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<R>(ranges)...
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> u{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::array<double, 3> v{ 6.1, 6.2, 6.3 };

    for (auto e: vsum(std::plus{}, u, v))
        std::cout << e << '\n';
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/5aGzKhbsT).

You can add type constraints if you want, but `vsum(std::plus{}, ...)` works automatically for everything with a suitable `operator+`.

I made it variadic because it was actually less typing for a quick demo, but there's no problem fixing it to two range parameters. Obviously it also generalizes with no effort to any number of dimensions.

Comment: Nice example, but likely few have gcc X86_64(trunk) available except on godbolt. g++ (GCC) 12.2.1 20230111 - won't. Neither will g++-12 (SUSE Linux) 12.2.1 20230124.

Comment: Perfectly true, but it's nice to have something to look forward to!

Comment: Chuckling -- so true...